# screen does not load if no touch or action is taken

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework

I have this code in ngOnInit (Home.page.ts)

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.publications = this.pubService.getPublications();
}
```

In my publication.service.ts, on the constructor i have this

```
  constructor(
    private afs: AngularFirestore
  ) {
    this.publicationCollection = this.afs.collection<PublicationModel>('publications', ref => ref.orderBy('createdAt', 'desc'));
    this.publications = this.publicationCollection.snapshotChanges().pipe(
      map(pub => {
        return pub.map(p => {
          const data = p.payload.doc.data();
          const id = p.payload.doc.id;
          return { id, ...data };
        });
      })
    );
  }
```

And, my function for get publications (publication.service.ts)

```
  getPublications() {
    return this.publications;
  }
```

My problem is, when I test my application on the cell phone, the home screen remains blank until I touch the screen or do some action on it.

Comment: check whether you are using changeDetection method in your component

Comment: I think I'm not using it  

`@Component({
  selector: 'app-tab1',
  templateUrl: 'tab1.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['tab1.page.scss']
})`